# probability moment generating functions, continuity theorem question

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I have managed to do most of the question, but can't get the very last part. We have $M_{2Np}(t)=M_N(2pt)$, but I don't seem to be getting a limiting gamma distribution.

For $Y$ I got the MGF as $\frac{p~\mathsf e^t}{(1-\mathsf e^t~(1-p))}$ (because Y has geometric distribution), and for $N$ I think it is a sum of $k$ independent random variables with the same distribution as $Y$, so the MGF should be $(M_Y(t))^k$ .

Would appreciate if someone could show me how to do the last part. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What did you get as the MGF of $N$?

Comment: As grand_chat asked, it's no use us showing how to complete the third step if we don't know that you have done the first steps okay.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry I should have written my answers for the first steps. For Y I got the MGF is p*exp(t)/(1-exp(t)*(1-p)) (because Y has geometric distribution), and for N I think it is a sum of k independent random variables with the same distribution as Y, so the MGF should be $(M_N(t))^k$ . Thank you for the help

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa Have you found the MGF of $X$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $M_N(2pt)$ in the form
$$
\left({p{\sf e}^{2pt}\over1 -(1-p){\sf e}^{2pt}}\right)^k.
$$
Look at the expression inside the big parentheses. When $p\downarrow0$, the expression is the indeterminate form $\frac00$. Apply L'Hopital's rule! To make your life easier, multiply top and bottom by ${\sf e}^{-2pt}$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have: $$M_N(t)= \dfrac{p^k~\mathsf e^{kt}}{(1-(1-p)\mathsf e^{t})^k}\qquad\color{green}\checkmark$$

Then by substitution. $$\begin{align}M_{2Np}(t) =&~ M_N(2pt) \\[1ex]=&~ \dfrac{p^k~\mathsf e^{2kpt}}{(1-(1-p)\mathsf e^{2pt})^k}\end{align}$$

Now show that $$M_X(t) = \lim\limits_{p\downarrow 0} M_{2Np}(t)$$

Where $M_X(t)$ is the MGF of $X$, the given Gamma distribution. (Hint: show the functions have the same form for some translation between $(\alpha, \lambda)$ and $(k, t)$ .)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I got the MGF of X to be $(λ/(λ-t))^k$ so I assume k will be our α in the end. My problem is, isn't the limit as p tends to zero just zero, or am I overlooking something.

Comment: As grand_chat sais, use l'Hopital's Rule. @lkjhgfdsa